# Amplitude amplification for known state but unknown amplitude

Tags: amplitude-amplification

I have a circuit that prepares a state $|s\rangle$ which is a superposition of the basis states $$\sum_{x=0}^{2^{n-1}}\alpha_x|x\rangle$$
with amplitude $\alpha_x$ for a circuit of $n$ qubits. Particularly, the solution to the problem I'm looking is on the state $|0\rangle$.

The challenge is that, $|0\rangle$ usually has a really low probability (and sometimes its not even present in the superposition).

I  was wondering if there was a simple way to boost the amplitude of $|0\rangle$ given I know specifically location of my solution?

Comment: Is $|0\rangle$ a subset of the $n$ qubits?  If it’s only $k\le n$ of these qubits why not use a conditional rotation based on these?

Comment: You mean a conditional rotation if state 0 is present? Could you please elaborate a little bit more on what kind of rotation you mean

Comment: Are you familiar with the idea that amplitude amplification and Grover's search are essentially the same thing? Are you aware that Grover's search can be used when there's an unknown number of solutions (making use of phase estimation)? You can put the two together...

Comment: Is this on the main paper?